# Archive file corrupt error but tmp dir is writable

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, update

I have a Joomla 3.4.5 running on an Azure web app and when I try to run the update to 3.6.0 I get the `The archive file is corrupt, truncated or archive parts are missing` error. I checked in system information and it says that my `/tmp` and `/log` directories are writable. From posts elsewhere I saw that it might be the max upload settings in PHP but I reset these using a `.user.ini` file to be 20M (the update file is about 10M) and the error still occurs. I checked my `/tmp` directory and sure enough the update file never made it into the directory, but uploading it manually via FileZilla doesn't seem to help, I still get the error. Does anyone have any suggestions what to try next? I've been trawling the web but can't see anything useful.

Comment: Did you try to extract the file locally to ensure the file integrity of the archive? Make sure there are no similar errors locally, first.

Comment: I have now tried extracting the .zip package on my local PC and it extracted ok. But the Update facility isn't even trying to extract the files, I assume, as it doesn't even write the file into the tmp folder in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach for you will be to manually update Joomla!. You can do this by following these steps:

### Before updating, always take a backup and don’t forget to test it.

1. Download the update package from https://www.joomla.org/download.html (Latest is currently [3.6.3 Update Package](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.6.3/Joomla_3.6.3-Stable-Update_Package.zip))
2. Extract the download package on your computer
3. Using your favorite FTP software, upload the folders and files at the root of the website or in the folder where your Joomla! installation is located. (**NOTE:** If you are using [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), click on "Replace" for all, if you are using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php), click on upload and then allow override for all. The FTP software will overwrite the existing files and add the new ones.)
4. Log in to your Joomla! Administrator panel and go to **Extensions → Manage → Database** and select the **Fix** button on the top left.
5. Go within the manage section to Discover menu item in the left menu and click the **Discover** button. Select only the **Joomla! CORE extensions** shown in the list and click the **Install** button. **(NOTE: do not select installation for the 3rd party extensions you may have installed)**.
6. In the main menu of your administrator panel, go to **System → Clear Cache** and if any rows are shown, select them and click the **Delete** button at the top left.

---

Sources: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5, https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/tag/3.6.3

Comment: Thanks Michael, that got it. When I considered manual update previously everything I looked at looked much more complicated including editing database tables and the like. This was much simpler and worked first time. Cheers.